# PHP Codeigniter, arrays, $db->insert_batch() function

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a problem with Codeigniter's insert_batch model function, it seems to rearrange the array that is passed on it in ascending. here's my code

Controller (gets all the post data and arrange it into an array):

```
    $product_id = $this->input->post('product_id');
    $colors = $this->input->post('color_name');
    $quantity = $this->input->post('product_quantity');
    $payment_option = $this->input->post('payment_option');
    $price = $this->input->post('product_price');

    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    $orders = array();
    $other_info = $this->business_mgmt->unique_details();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($product_id); $i++) {
        $color_id = $this->products_model->select_color_id($colors[$i]);

        $orders[] = array( 
                        'order_id' => null,
                        'invoice_number' => $other_info[0],
                        'customer_number' => $other_info[1],
                        'user_id' => 1,
                        'product_id' => $product_id[$i],
                        'color_id' => $color_id,
                        'quantity' => $quantity[$i],
                        'price' => $price[$i],
                        'order_date' => $date
                    );
    }

    $this->business_mgmt->insert_order($orders);
```

and here's the model:

```
    function insert_order($order_details) {
         $this->db->insert_batch('exp_mcc_orders', $order_details); 
         print '<pre>';
         print_r($order_details);
         print '</pre>';
    }
```

and here's the error message:

```
    Error Number: 1062

    Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

    INSERT INTO `exp_mcc_orders` 
    (`color_id`, `customer_number`, `invoice_number`,`order_date`, `order_id`, `price`,
    `product_id`, `quantity`, `user_id`) 
    VALUES ('2','260','20130876617','2013-08-27',NULL,'15','4','4',1)

    Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\MiracleCandleCompany\website\system\database\DB_driver.php
```

Line Number: 330

Advance thanks.
The right order of the columns in my database is the one I used on my array.
The problem is codeigniter rearranges it in ascending.

Comment: I don't know the framework you're using, but the order of columns does not matter. The problem is your primary key doesn't auto-increment.

Comment: Please make your question titles more descriptive in the future. “PHP CodeIgniter” doesn’t really help people in searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove key `order_id` from array `$orders`. Also You can check settings of table `exp_mcc_orders` for column `order_id` - set auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

Just got it working, my order_id(primary key) isn't set to auto_increment and I mistakenly set the other columns into UNIQUE KEY.